# How do I join a sql date table with a table of sales without dates falling out?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a sales table in `BigQuery` that consists of multiple items and their corresponding sales data at the daily level, by sales channels (KR_DC and KR_SHOP):

[image]

I have a base calendar table consisting of six years of daily dates and a column for the two channels:

[image]

Using my calendar table as a base, when I try to left join the sales table with the goal of having every day represented in the final table for every item we sell, my results only return days of no sells when zero items sold.

My desire is that for every item, the table has each day/channel combination represented, even if that item does not sell (for later sales forecast modeling).

What is the best way to pull each unique item from the sales table and conduct a query that joins to the base calendar table so that every day is represented.  I realize that I will have to fill down the descriptive data fields that describe the item being sold.

Is there a way to do this without a loop?

When I try a normal left join, I end up with missing data. If you see, days are missing between November 27 and December 4th of 2020.  I would like to have those days present with `0` in the `order_qty` and `demand_usd`  columns.  Then I can use the `Last_Value` function to fill the other columns down.
[image]
Below is the SQL I'm using.

```
Select * from (
with date_table as (
SELECT 'KR_DC' as iso_loc_type
,calendar_date
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), Interval 1 Year), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS calendar_date

UNION ALL
SELECT 'KR_SHOP' as iso_loc_type
,calendar_date
FROM UNNEST(
    GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 5 YEAR), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), Interval 1 Year), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
) AS calendar_date order by calendar_date
)

,sales as (
SELECT   
location.fcmicro_corp_cd
,sales_history.ord_dt
,sales_history.fcast_item
,location.iso_loc_type
-- ,MAX(item_master.GLBL_BUS_LN_DESC) as glbl_bus_ln_desc
-- ,MAX(item_master.GLBL_CTGRY_DESC) as glbl_ctgry_desc
-- ,MAX(item_master.GLBL_SUB_CTGRY_DESC) as glbl_sub_ctgry_desc
-- ,MAX(item_master.GLBL_PRDCT_IND_CUT_DESC) as glbl_prdct_ind_cut_desc
-- ,MAX(item_master.ITEM_DESC) as item_desc
-- ,c.intro_dt
-- ,IFNULL(promo_base.promotion_type, 'regular_item') as promotion_type
,CAST(item_price.DCOST_USD as FLOAT64) as dcost_usd
,CAST(item_price.DCOST_LOCAL as FLOAT64) as dcost_local
,sum(sales_history.ord_qty) as ord_qty
,sum(sales_history.demand_usd) as demand_usd

FROM `gcp-vc-planning-prod.09_curation.sales_history_summary` sales_history


LEFT OUTER JOIN `gcp-vc-planning-prod.09_mdm.location` location 
on sales_history.loc = location.loc

LEFT JOIN `gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.ITEM_MASTER` item_master 
on sales_history.fcast_item = item_master.ITEM_NO
and location.fcmicro_corp_cd = item_master.CORP_CD
and item_master.CORP_CD = "180"

LEFT JOIN (select distinct(ITEM_NO), MAX(INTRO_DT) as intro_dt, corp_cd 
        from gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.ITEM_MASTER
        where corp_cd = "180"
        group by ITEM_NO, corp_cd) c
        on sales_history.fcast_item = c.ITEM_NO

left join `gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.ITEM_PRICE` item_price
on sales_history.fcast_item = item_price.ITEM_NO
and PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', CONCAT(CAST(item_price.YR AS STRING), '-', LPAD(CAST(item_price.MO AS STRING), 2, '0'), '-', LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(item_price.YR, item_price.MO, 1), MONTH))) AS STRING), 2, '0'), 'T00:00:00')) = PARSE_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S', CONCAT(CAST(EXTRACT(YEAR from sales_history.ord_dt) AS STRING), '-', LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(MONTH from sales_history.ord_dt) AS STRING), 2, '0'), '-', LPAD(CAST(EXTRACT(DAY FROM LAST_DAY(DATE_TRUNC(DATE(EXTRACT(YEAR from sales_history.ord_dt), EXTRACT(MONTH from sales_history.ord_dt), 1), MONTH))) AS STRING), 2, '0'), 'T00:00:00'))
and item_price.CORP_CD = "180"

WHERE
right(sales_history.fcast_item, 3) not in ('PAT', 'SVC')
and sales_history.fcast_item <> ""
and location.fcmicro_corp_cd = "180"
and sales_history.ord_dt <= DATE_ADD(DATE_SUB(DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), MONTH), INTERVAL 1 DAY), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)

GROUP BY
fcmicro_corp_cd
,sales_history.ord_dt
,sales_history.fcast_item
,location.iso_loc_type
,c.intro_dt
,item_price.DCOST_USD 
,item_price.DCOST_LOCAL

ORDER BY
location.iso_loc_type
,sales_history.fcast_item
,sales_history.ord_dt
)

Select date_table.calendar_date
,sales.*

from date_table 
left join sales
on date_table.calendar_date = sales.ord_dt 
and date_table.iso_loc_type = sales.iso_loc_type

order by sales.fcast_item, date_table.calendar_date, sales.iso_loc_type)
```

If I were to add a filter inside the join to one item like the following:
`and sales.fcast_item = '100179K'` then the table does come out like I would expect:
[image]

The above table would allow me to fill in the `ord_qty` and `demand_usd` with `0` and fill down the other null columns with the last populated row's data. Which leads me to believe there may be a way to do this join by item.

Comment: Your left join is the correct way to go. `CALENDAR LEFT JOIN SALES`, you just need to be extra careful to not add a condition in your `WHERE` clause that filters the `SALES` table otherwise you accidentally turn that `LEFT OUTER JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`. If there is a need to filter `SALES` before the join, do it either in your `ON` clause or in a subquery. If that isn't the answer, then share your sql attempt so we can help.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I added more information and sql code for context.

Comment: Quoting site [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc**.—copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `cross join` in the date_table CTE instead of repeating the date series each time. e.g:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    WITH date_table AS (
            SELECT
                  iso_loc_type
                , calendar_date
            FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE (), INTERVAL 5 YEAR), DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE (), Interval 1 Year), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) AS calendar_date
            CROSS JOIN (
                   SELECT 'KR_DC' AS iso_loc_type
                   union all
                   SELECT 'KR_SHOP' AS iso_loc_type
                ) cj
```

Later you define the sales CTE which includes this:

```
            , sales_history.ord_dt
```

What we don't know is if that column is "just a date" (without time) or a timestamp to sub-second precision. If it is "just a date" then you can join the sales data to the date_table OK. If it has timestamp precision then you need to  modify how you join to the date_table.

Later in that ame sales CTE you use:

```
            SELECT DISTINCT (ITEM_NO)
                , MAX(INTRO_DT) AS intro_dt
                , corp_cd
            ...
            GROUP BY ITEM_NO
                , corp_cd
```

Using "select distinct" and also using "group by" is unnecessary (because group by produces "distinct" rows by itself). Also distinct is NOT a function so you can remove the redundant parentheses around `(ITEM_NO)`.

As mentioned earlier if `sales.ord_dt` is "just a date" then the current join is fine:

```
SELECT date_table.calendar_date
    , sales.*
FROM date_table
LEFT JOIN sales
    ON date_table.calendar_date = sales.ord_dt
        AND date_table.iso_loc_type = sales.iso_loc_type
```

However if `sales.ord_dt` more than just date but includes time information as well then the join needs amendment to compare `sales.ord_dt` to a date range e.g:

```
SELECT date_table.calendar_date
    , sales.*
FROM date_table
LEFT JOIN sales
    ON sales.ord_dt >= date_table.calendar_date
        AND sales.ord_dt < date_add(date_table.calendar_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        AND date_table.iso_loc_type = sales.iso_loc_type
```

Using the date_table and left joining to your sales data should meet the need to "fill-in" the missing days.